# Boot volume full

Tags: boot, directory

How do I find hidden "boot" folder on my ubuntu 14.04 pc? If I am able to find it, will I mess up anything by clicking on unused kernel and hitting delete button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Boot directory is not hidden, you can easily find it by clicking "Computer" in your file manager. But do not just delete files from there. It will break all your system. To remove unused kernels you can use synaptic.
And generally it is not a good idea to have a separate /boot partition for a desktop computer.
[Here is a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not hidden. If you want to remove some older/unused kernels, do not do this with a file manager, but through command-line or synaptic (I recommend command-line). For this, you need to find the name of the kernel you want to remove. Boot Ubuntu with this kernel, open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command

```
uname -r
```

Take note of the output.

Now reboot with the kernel you want to keep. Open Terminal and remove the unused kernel with the commands

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-*here comes the output you noted*
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-*output again*
sudo update-initramfs -d -k *output*
sudo update-grub
```

And you are done. If possible, NEVER do this process with a file manager (nautilus, for example). You could remove some important file and then your system would become a mess.

*Note:* Do not include the *'s in the commands you will run.